# Specific rows from CSV as dictionary and logic when keys are the same - Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

```
abc11  bvc  ex  123  456  somestuffhere
abc11  bvc  ex  456  476  somestuffhere
abc12  bvc  ex  173  426  somestuffhere
abc12  bvc  ex  426  496  somestuffhere
abc13  bvc  ex  143  796  somestuffhere
abc13  bvc  ex  743  896  somestuffhere
```

I am trying to put the above CSV file as a dictionary, `{'abc11':['123','476'],'abc12':['173','496'],'abc13':['143','896']}`. I want the zeroth column values as keys and the third and the fourth columns as values, only the minimum(or the third) and the maximum(or the fourth) values when the keys are the same. I am also not sure if it is best if the values are as a list inside a dictionary as I need to check these values with another list later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the whole dictionary first, with the lists containing all the values for each key. Then once the dictionary is made, you can go through every key and take the largest and smallest values.

```
yourdict = dict()

with open(file) as f:
   filedata = f.read().splitlines()
   for line in filedata:
       linedata = line.split()
       if linedata[0] not in yourdict:
           yourdict[linedata[0]] = []
       yourdict[linedata[0]].append(int(linedata[3]))
       yourdict[linedata[0]].append(int(linedata[4]))

for key in yourdict:
    yourdict[key] = [min(yourdict[key]), max(yourdict[key])]
```

Also, your above file isn't a CSV file, a CSV file is a Comma Separated File. Your file is separated by spaces, my code is for a file separated by spaces, not a CSV. It's easy to change though if you will truly have a CSV file.

Comment: Sorry, the elements in the file are separated by tabs, and I just put in a sample of it.

Comment: Well then the code I put up still works! the split() function by python splits by any whitespace, including tabs. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! It almost worked perfectly, but a few values seem to be interchanged, i.e 'key': ['max value', 'min value'] and for some some of the minimum values are not displayed. Is this cause of a dictionary error? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I'll need the actual inputs and outputs to figure out the problem quarters.

Comment: I think it is because some of the data is like: the abc values are repeated at intervals. `abc11  bvc  ex  123  456  somestuffhere` `abc12  bvc  ex  426  496  somestuffhere` and then another `abc11  bvc  ex  456  476  somestuffhere`. I think cause of this a display of: `'abc11': ['476', '456'] is present.

Comment: `abc11  bvc  ex  123  456  somestuffhere`
`abc12  bvc  ex  173  426  somestuffhere`
`abc11  bvc  ex  456  476  somestuffhere`
`abc13  bvc  ex  143  796  somestuffhere`
`abc12  bvc  ex  426  496  somestuffhere`
`abc13  bvc  ex  743  896  somestuffhere`

Comment: With that input, I get `{'abc12': ['173', '496'], 'abc13': ['143', '896'], 'abc11': ['123', '476']}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80599/discussion-between-quarters-and-jellyb0x3r).

Comment: The problem could possibly be that I'm inputting them into the dictionary as strings, I will edit the code to cast them as ints, try it then.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
d = {}

with open(file) as f:
   for line in f:
       if line.split()[0] not in d:
           d[line.split()[0]] = [line.split()[3],line.split()[4]]
       else:
           d[line.split()[0]] = [min(line.split()[3],d[line.split()[0]][0]), max(line.split()[4],d[line.split()[0]][1])]
```